# Loop update existing excel template

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to write a script where I currently have an excel VBA sheet that has two tabs with 1st being a graph and second being a backend file. Backend is updated by a master file. In the master file there is a city column where I want to loop through all the unique city rows write those rows in to the VBA file and save the VBA file with the city's name.

```
master_backend = pd.read_excel(path)
city = master_backend[(master_backend["City"]=="NY")] 

def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                      truncate_sheet=False, 
                      **to_excel_kwargs):
   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   import pandas as pd
   if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
       to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') 
   try:
       FileNotFoundError
   except NameError:
       FileNotFoundError = IOError
   try:        
       writer.book = load_workbook(filename, keep_vba = True)
       if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
           startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row
       if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
           idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
           writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
           writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)
       writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
   except FileNotFoundError:
       pass
   if startrow is None:
       startrow = 0
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
   writer.save()
```

Essentially what I want is 5 files since there are 5 cities all named with their city name

Answer (score 0):

as I don't know VBA and you posted this under the python tag I'll provide my take on this.

assuming your datasheet is called `file` you could try something like this :

```
import shutil
for city in master_backend.City.unique():
    df = master_backend.loc[master_backend.City == city]
    shutil.copy(file,f"{city}.xlsx")
    append_df_excel(f"{city}.xlsx", df,sheet_name='Backend')
```

cracking function btw, I would use put some doc strings in it for easy of use : )

Comment: So that would ideally work but I have no control of the vba file which I just update backends for. It is also an xlsm file so I have to use openpyxl and the backend fill starts at row 4...so lots of nuances that I am trying to work around haha

Comment: hmm it's not clear to me what you want, you want to replace a datasheet in a vba file which is .xlsm ? you can still replace that with your `append_df_excel` function call?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this script significantly by understanding that pandas will create a dataframe for you when you read the excel file.  Then it's just a simple matter of collecting the info you want from the dataframe and re-writting it to a file.  It's unclear what you want in your new file, but suppose you just want to filter the second sheet and keep everything in the first sheet it might look like this.

```
# Open the file, 
# NOTE: when you open the file, if there are multiple sheets 
#   then the result is a dictionary of dataframes keyed on the sheet name
master_data = pd.read_excel(file_path, ....)

# Assuming second sheet name is 'City'
city_df=master_data['City']

# Replace 'columnName' with the name of the column (if includes headers) or column number
for city in pd.unique(city_df['columnName']):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(city + '.xlsx') as writer:
        master_data['Sheet1'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        city_df[city_df['columnName']==city].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='City')
```

Comment: I think the problem of doing this with pure pandas is that it will over write the datasheet and lose all connections and formulas,which is why he has the self defined function above. Nice answer tho, you could use f strings with city go make it more readable imo (: